# mySQL Like $query - Using a GET variable as the %LIKE% value

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am using a mySQL query which currently looks for just one value in this as such;

```
 "SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE tabID LIKE '%spotlight%'";
```

this sits on index.php and this works great, however I would like the search value "spotlight" not to be hard coded, but so it is achieved from the URL

So when I go to

```
index.php?type=spotlight
```

ill get spotlights. and when I go to

```
index.php?type=lamps
```

I will get lamps

**I have player around with this** and at I am sure its something like this which I have been trying to make work...

```
$product_type = $_GET['type'];

       //*    and then lower down where the query sits *\\

"SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE tabID LIKE '%$product_type%'";
```

but it really didn't like this and eded up showing all values for the $usertable

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards

Henry

Comment: How are you passing the queries in through php?

Comment: Make sure you're using `PDO`, or you're liable to get hacked

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection This is the only possible outcome of this approach :)

Comment: and of course http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Try to echo your SQL statement first to make sure that the statement was correct. But you're also not recommended to use this approach though.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM $usertable WHERE tabID LIKE '$type'";
```

removing the % although changes the search criteria, to must contain exactly, did the trick.